# Not able to fill multiple rows in xfa pdf with FillXfaForm() using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, xfa

I was trying with below code to fill multiple rows in xfa pdf using FillXfaForm() method in C#.net. Anyone please guide me what is wrong on this code. We are using itexsharp.dll version 5.5.4.0.

```
public void manipulatePdf()
{
using (FileStream existingPdf = new FileStream "existingPdf.pdf",FileMode.Open))
using (FileStream sourceXml = new FileStream("sourceXml.xml", FileMode.Open))
using (FileStream newPdf = new FileStream("mymergedPdf.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{ 
// Open existing PDF  
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingPdf); 
// PdfStamper, which will create  
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newPdf); 
AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
XfaForm xfa = form.Xfa;
xfa.FillXfaForm(sourceXml);
stamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
} 
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a pure XFA form (see for instance the [XfaMovies](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165) example) [1] or a hybrid XFA form (see for instance the [XfaMovie](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=164) example [2])? In [1], you have a repeating subform that makes that rows are repeated. If no such form is defined, no extra rows will be added. In [2], you have a *static* XFA form and it is impossible to add extra rows automatically. If you want an answer, you will have to show us your PDF (I bet it's not pure XFA). Without your PDF, your question is unanswerable.